# How do I get MuPAD to stop using placeholders for matrix elements?

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math, mupad

I'm trying to evaluate some matrix multiplications in MuPAD. The output is using sigmas as placeholders for the matrix elements since they are long expressions (I assume that's the reason). Is there a way to get MuPAD to display the individual matrix elements as (in my case) the exponential functions that they really are, regardless of the length of the expression?

Below is an example of a case where MuPAD is using sigmas instead of the actual exponential functions. I would like to be able to see what the individual matrix elements of `TotT^4` really are.

[image: example MuPAD equation]

The commands I executed in the MuPAD interface that lead up to `TotT^4` are:

```
T1 := matrix([[exp((J+B/2)/T),exp(-(J+B/6)/T)],[exp((-J+B/6)/T),exp((J-B/2)/T)]])
T2 := matrix([[exp((J1+B/2)/T),exp(-(J1+B/6)/T)],[exp((-J1+B/6)/T),exp((J1-B/2)/T)]])
T1d := linalg::transpose(T1)
TotT := T1d*T2
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the MuPAD code that generated `TotT` or a simple small runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

The class of your variable can be obtain via `type(totT)`: `Dom::Matrix`. You may want to look at the [many methods of this class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom-matrix.html#expanderlistentry__divide) in the documentation. As far as I can tell, this issue has something to do with the pretty printing of the class's [`print` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom-matrix.html#expanderlistentry_print). Other classes exhibit this same substitution, so it may be a function of the overloaded [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/print.html). I was not able to change the behavior by adjusting `setPrintMaxSize`, [`PRETTYPRINT`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/prettyprint.html), [`TEXTWIDTH`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/textwidth.html), or any of the optional arguments to `print`. You might still try yourself as there are many permutations.

I also tried using the [`expand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/expand.html) function. `expand(TotT,IgnoreAnalyticConstraints)` nearly works though it could have undesirable effects in some cases if things were expanded too much. Calling [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) does get rid go the substitutions, but it also changes the nature of some of the entries by simplifying. It is probably also not a general solution to this issue.

One way that does work, but is ugly, is to use the [`expr2text` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom-matrix.html#expanderlistentry_expr2text), which returns a result as a string:

```
expr2text(TotT)
```

which returns

```
"matrix([[exp((B/6 - J)/T)*exp((B/6 - J1)/T) + exp((B/2 + J)/T)*exp((B/2 + J1)/T), ...
          exp(-(B/2 - J1)/T)*exp((B/6 - J)/T) + exp((B/2 + J)/T)*exp(-(B/6 + J1)/T)], ...
         [exp(-(B/2 - J)/T)*exp((B/6 - J1)/T) + exp((B/2 + J1)/T)*exp(-(B/6 + J)/T), ...
          exp(-(B/2 - J)/T)*exp(-(B/2 - J1)/T) + exp(-(B/6 + J)/T)*exp(-(B/6 + J1)/T)]])"
```

I think that this question would be a good one to ask over at [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) or by filing a [service request](https://mathworksservicerequest.secure.force.com/cp_case_new) if you have a license with support.